# Inline javascript filter that returns sub object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I am trying to call the filter method on an array of objects, but I do not want to return the whole object. I just want to return a part of the object.

```
[
   {val: 0, val2: 'a'},
   {val: 1, val2: 'b'},
   {val: 2, val2: 'c'},
   {val: 3, val2: 'd'}
].filter( obj => {
    if (obj.val > 1){
        return obj.val2
}})
```

This filter function returns

```
[ { val: 2, val2: 'c' }, { val: 3, val2: 'd' } ]
```

But should be returning

```
[ { val2: 'c' }, { val2: 'd' } ]
```

---

The problem with using `map` is that I don't want undefined being injected into the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use `reduce` for this, keep it to 1 iteration and only push items in the array that you want to keep.

```js
const result = [
   {val: 0, val2: 'a'},
   {val: 1, val2: 'b'},
   {val: 2, val2: 'c'},
   {val: 3, val2: 'd'}
].reduce((prev, obj) => {
    if (obj.val > 1)
        prev.push({ val2: obj.val2 });
    return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more, so obj is the item which holds the value for the current iteration, and prev get's assigned to the empty array that you initialize at the end somehow?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Array.prototype.reduce takes 2 arguments, a callback function and an initial value. For each iteration, the first argument of the callback function is the last returned value. At the first ireration, the `prev`ious value will be the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine map and filter.

```
dataArray.filter(obj => obj.val > 1 && obj.val2).map(obj => obj.val2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to construct a new object on iterations that pass, you can use `.map` to transform all of the passing objects after filtering:

```js
const result = [
   {val: 0, val2: 'a'},
   {val: 1, val2: 'b'},
   {val: 2, val2: 'c'},
   {val: 3, val2: 'd'}
]
  .filter(obj => obj.val > 1)
  .map(({ val2 }) => ({ val2 }));
console.log(result);
```

Or, by only iterating over the array once:

```js
const input = [
   {val: 0, val2: 'a'},
   {val: 1, val2: 'b'},
   {val: 2, val2: 'c'},
   {val: 3, val2: 'd'}
]
const result = [];
for (const { val, val2 } of input) {
  if (val > 1) result.push({ val2 });
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `map()` as well:

```js
var res = [
   {val: 0, val2: 'a'},
   {val: 1, val2: 'b'},
   {val: 2, val2: 'c'},
   {val: 3, val2: 'd'}
].filter( obj => {
    if (obj.val > 1){
        return obj.val2
}}).map(i => ({val2:i.val2}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your mindset a bit and understand how to achieve your goal.

Look, you wanna get all `val2` property values only when value of property `val` is grather than 1 - in this case you have to split your job to 2 microtasks:
1. filter the array and remove all useless cases
2. get your property value

## Here you go:

```js
const arr = [
  { val: 0, val2: 'a' },
  { val: 1, val2: 'b' },
  { val: 2, val2: 'c' },
  { val: 3, val2: 'd' },
];

const res = arr.filter(({ val }) => val > 1)
                .map(({ val2 }) => ({val2}));

console.log(res)
```